# How to make a list of recent/running apps

Tags: java, android

When holding the home button on your phone a pop up comes up showing recent applications. Does anyone know how to do this same action through code?  I need to be able to choose one in a listview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Recent and Running application list not processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376646/get-recent-and-running-application-list-not-processes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`getRunningTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)

From the docs:

`public List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks (int maxNum)`

`Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, with the most recent being first and older ones after in order`

Comment: Thanks seems pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

[getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) sounds like a method that could help you at whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [getRecentTasks(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) also.
This should show the history, whether or not the app is still "running"