# Android: How to get recent tasks list and origActivity?

Tags: android, task, activity-manager

I'd want to get recent task list.

I use the following code, but when I try to get origActivity info, origActivity is always null:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(8,0);
```

I want to know application label, package name and activity name of all activities of the list.

The only way to know these elements is to use origActivity from RecentTaskInfo but it is always null (I get a NullPOinterException).

The only information that I can get is the Activity id.

There is a way to know application label, package name and activity name of all recent task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Recent and Running application list not processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376646/get-recent-and-running-application-list-not-processes)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the package name and class name , go with the base intent variable. The example below taken from getView() function from AdapterView.

```
final ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo temp = this.getItem(position); 
final String packagename = temp.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
final String label = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA))
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this code to initialze acitivty manager

```
     activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

and why dont you use

```
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> rpinfo= activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

from this u can get all the information you want
and the list is sorted according to the recent task. Means latest used task is at the top
to u can get as many recent task you want
And to get the application label

```
PackageManager pm=getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();  
ApplicationInfo ai;

try {
    ai=pm.getApplicationInfo(processName, 0);
    name=(String) pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I know getRunningTasks, but I want the recent task not the running.

Comment: go through this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Comment: "and the list is sorted according to the recent task" this is unfortunately not true. As stated out in the API, the ordering is not specified and a lot devices will *not* order the list with the recent at top.

Answer (score -1):

you must hold this permission
`GET_TASKS`

Comment: OP already got the activity id, I assume he/she holds the permission already.