# Get info about all running processes

Tags: java, android, taskmanager

I have an idea to make **Task Manager** for android.Can anyone tell me how to get all the processes **currently running** in android?

Comment: You can't. You can get all the running processes, by reading the output of `ps,` but you can't manage them, except by exec-ing other programs, which already exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this Question is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using the code below you can get the list of running  processes:-

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(RunningAppProcessInfo runningProInfo:procInfos){

        Log.d("Running Processes", "()()"+runningProInfo.processName);
}
```

**For more information you can visit [this link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)**

*To get the application name based on package name use `PackageManager` class.*

```
final PackageManager pkgmgr = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appinfo;
try {
    appinfo = pkgmgr.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    appinfo = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (appinfo != null ? pkgmgr.getApplicationLabel(appinfo) : "(unknown)");
```

*To get the app name on the basis of PID use:-*

```
public static String getAppNameByPID(Context context, int pid){
    ActivityManager manager 
               = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()){
        if(processInfo.pid == pid){
            return processInfo.processName;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

***and finally*** to check if an app is system app or not use:-

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return (pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & 
                ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
    }
```

Comment: any permissions to mention in menifest?

Comment: @zaidiqbal `android.permission.GET_TASKS`

Comment: It also returns a lot of system processes?

Comment: Also it is returning package names not actual app name.Any solution?

Comment: @zaidiqbal then please checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12376775/3837191)

Comment: How to get app name through package name?

Comment: Now last thing . how can i get pid through package name?

Comment: @zaidiqbal Check the last part of my edited answer.

Comment: `manager.getRunningAppProcesses()` gives a lot of tasks While     
`manager.getRecentTasks()` gives some tasks.
**Why**?
**What is difference b/w them**?

Comment: `getRunningAppProcesses()`
returns a list of application processes that are running on the device while `getRecentTasks(int maxNum, int flags)`
returns a list of the tasks that the user has recently launched, with the most recent being first and older ones after in order. Here `maxNum`is the maximum number of entries to return in the list. The actual number returned may be smaller, depending on how many tasks the user has started and the maximum number the system can remember.

Comment: edited my answer. hope I helped :)

Comment: Note that from API 29, a regular app cannot access the list of other processes.