# How to determine who has launched a deep link into my app

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-security, android-deep-link

I need to find out which app is launching a deep link into my app for security purposes

Has anyone done this before?

There are some solutions such as [Using Pending intents to find creator package name](http://s0hungry.com/2017/08/05/android-getcallingpackage-returns-null-and-an-alternative/) but it didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getReferrer().getHost()` to get the package name of the app that launched your app.

For example, if a link was launched from Google docs that launched your app, it would return `com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs`.

See [Activity#getReferrer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer()), but as the doc notes, if an app wanted to spoof it or leave it empty, it could. So, not 100%.

Otherwise, resort to something like [Get Recent and Running application list not processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376646/get-recent-and-running-application-list-not-processes) and get the last app/activity before yours.