# Close all recent open/running apps at once button-android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to close all recent apps at once. I found the following code, but it only shows recent apps. I want to close all these recent apps.

Show all recent app list code: (but I don't want list i need to close all recent apps)

```
Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerClass, "statusbar");
Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder.getInterfaceDescriptor());
Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0].getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null, new Object[] { retbinder });
Method clearAll = statusBarClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
clearAll.setAccessible(true);
clearAll.invoke(statusBarObject);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All recent app closed....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799357/how-to-close-kill-an-android-app-programmatically-without-leaving-it-in-the-back

Comment: it just hide your current app from recent app list ,my problem is to clear or close all opened recent apps

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not possible to *kill & remove from "Recent apps" list* user's recent apps, even with `Process.killProcess()` method.
Read these two answers:
  - [Kill another application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037227/1658267)
  - [How to kill currently running task in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8849562/1658267)

**However**, what you can do is to ***restart*** the background processes of the recent apps (that's what most TaskKillers from Google Play actually do):

- Add `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` user-permission into your manifest:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
  ```
- And then `killBackgroundProcesses`(previously known as `restartPackage`) for the process/processes you want to "kill" (even though it's not actual killing)

  ```
  ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
          this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
  List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningProInfo:procInfos){
      if (runningProInfo.processName.equals("PACKAGE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_KILL")) {
          actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(runningProInfo.processName);
      }
  }
  ```

As a result, "killed" apps, no longer presented in the list of running process, they are removed from memory. Apps are **still** in list of recent apps and you can't do anything with it - see answer  [clear all recent task Programmaticcally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350032/1658267)

I hope, it helps.

Comment: what is "PACKAGE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_KILL" i think it should procInfos.Name what you think?and also i think it will only kill running apps i want to clear all apps which shows in recent history list which show on "Home" button long press

Comment: @sms247 for example, `com.android.chrome`(i.e processName actually equals to the app's package), once you want to stop Chrome browser. To get list of only recently running apps - use `getRunningTasks` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870487/how-to-make-a-list-of-recent-running-apps). But again, they **won't** be removed from the list of recent apps (unless you are device manufacturer)

Answer (score 6):

Quitting an application is the job of the Android OS. Consider the reasons you want to quit all the recent applications. If all the recent applications are not written properly, with respect to the Android OS application development model, and they're misbehaving, then they should be uninstalled or fixed.

Here is a wonderful wiki on the subject:

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Comment: i know its not possible but i have idea if i got code which will return all process ids then i use this line Process.killProcess(Process.myPid()) in forloop so kill all apps but i am not sure it will also clear from recent app list

Comment: i'm not sure if my answer is clear to you, so let me try again here: don't kill apps like that.

Answer (score 0):

First is to get all activities running as what Konstantin Loginov said but instead of having it killed like putting its name. It may be better if checking also includes verification of process names listed under your recent apps if they are in your running processes.

After that, remove the list under your recent apps. You may want to take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list).